# Gradle : Dependency not getting added to classpath

Tags: java, gradle, dropwizard

I have added below dependency in build.gradle file. Eclipse plugin is added in build.gradle.

```
testCompile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:1.2.0'
```

Once I run gradle eclipse command all the compile dependencies are getting added in classpath but testcompile dependencies are not getting added in classpath.

But testCompile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:1.2.0' also has transitive dependencies like mockito. Therefore whenever I am trying to use mockito in my Junit, those are not getting compiled.

I am not sure what is the problem none of the transitive dependency of io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:1.2.0 is available

Comment: i was expecting io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:1.2.0 to add the transitive dependencies automatically but need to add mockito dependency also in build.gradle file and that solve the problem

Comment: Sorry, but is the problem that dropwizard-testing is not added or that mockito is not added. Or both? In general, if you depend on mockito, you should make it explicit dependency instead of pulling it as transitive dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the dropwizard-testing dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-testing/1.2.0) I can't see mockito in the compile scoped dependencies. It's in the test scoped dependencies but that's irrelevant, test scoped dependencies are private to that project and don't become transitive dependencies when the jar is included in another project.